# Can't send email to myself

Tags: opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.1.3. For some reason I can't send an email to the same account I am sending from. For example, I can't receive the notification email when an order is placed. The email reaches the customer OK and if I specify additional email address to send the mail to, they receive the email OK, the email configured as the store email addres doesn't receive the email. I'm using the 'mail' option to send email.

The email is hosted at google apps. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some web hosting prevent self-to-self email for safety reason.
maybe it is your hosting provider block this mail.

Comment: Turns out I needed to change a setting in whm to remote mail exchange.